# Dualboot troubles with Linux Ubuntu and Windows8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8

I dont know how to dualboot the system. I can only change the boot option in BIOS and then boot either windows or linux. When I have set a Linux boot option and after starting a computer i choose to click on windows8 an error shows up: 
error: unknown command 'drivemap'
error: invalid EFI file path

Answer (score 0):

you have to turn off fast boot and disable secure boot before installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.

This is a [great](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html) tutorial to learn from.

If you need more help just ask :)